# Search for an API gateway in a microservice architecture

Tags: microservices, traefik, api-gateway, envoyproxy

I am looking for a suitable API gateway for my project. I have looked at traefik with authelia and envoy but they don't fit 100 percent. Does anyone know of any other tools you can recommend to me?

Requirements:

- sticky session
- ldap authentication
- JWT
- not Java
- no cloud solution
- compatible with a Service Registry (e.g. Consul)
- support Websockets/gRPC
- compatible with prometheus would be nice